# How do I inlude a jsp file within another file?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, java-ee-6

I know how to import classes and libraries, if I have `header.jsp` and I want to include it within my `index.jsp`... I've been looking into the @page annotation but am having trouble finding a list of parameters.

Is this the wrong approach altogether?  If I'm going to be setting up header and footer files should I use a completely different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a jsp page in another [either statically or dynamically](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/05/22/difference-between-static-include-and-dynamic-include-in-jsp/). Each has its own syntax and usage recommendation. In your case, I believe static include is what is needed.